# How can I save a Zoom recording shared with me?

Tags: video, recording, zoom-meeting

I've received a web link to a Zoom recording. At the link, an in-page player opens, and the video starts playing. I can see that the page is issuing an HTTP GET request for an MP4 file with a bunch of parameters; but - I can't just retrieve that MP4, I get a "missing key", or a "Forbidden" if I also add the parameters.

How can I save the recording as an MP4 file (or in any other format) on my system?

Note: The link format is

```
https://us06web.zoom.us/rec/play/longstringofcharshere?startTime=foo&_x_zm_rtaid=bar&_x_zm_rhtaid=baz
```

Comment: When I use my Zoom (free personal account) and save the recording, it is stored in a local file. Maybe the host of the meeting can send you the file, if he has...

Answer (score 3):

As a last resort you can often use OBS to record your screen while you play it back. This does unfortunately require you to wait the entire length of the recording.

[The OBS project.](https://obsproject.com/)

Once you have OBS downloaded and open you'll see in the bottom middle a box that says "Sources".

Add either

- a "Window Capture", then create a new one, then pick the web browser window you have the zoom recording open in
- a "Display Capture", then create a new one, then pick the display (if you have multiple) you have the zoom recording open on

Two monitors will help here so that you can have the zoom recording on one and OBS on the other.

(If one doesn't work for you try the other.)

Then in the bottom right click "Start recording" and then in the web browser start the zoom recording going.

Once the zoom recording has finished playing back you can stop OBS recording.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the basics of a terminal, you can use [ZoomDL](https://github.com/Battleman/zoomdl). It works on Windows, Linux, Mac and should allow you to download any video, assuming you have the permissions to view the video (password, credentials,...). You can also download the chat and transcript (if any), and is compatible with "clips".

Disclaimer: I'm the creator

Answer (score 1):

When there is a recording of Zoom meetings, the recording is saved in a local file at the machine of the host that recorded the video. You probably received a link that does not allow you to download or open the video from outside your company (or without authentication). My company does that to prevent confidential information leakage, since nobody from outside should be allowed to see/know private information. Maybe that is the case for you...

By the url you shared in the question, it seems the host of the meeting is using [Zoom's Cloud Recordings](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/205347605-Managing-and-sharing-cloud-recordings) tool. It allows the sharing of the file to other people, but the owner can block downloads (specifying it on the [Viewers can download settings](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/205347605-Managing-and-sharing-cloud-recordings#h_750e7e94-45e4-415b-a67a-ac8b49e74fa2)). If you believe you should have access to the file, I advise you to get in contact with the host that recorded and shared the video - he might change that settings or just send you the file some other way. However, as I mentioned before, some companies does that (block downloads) to avoid information leakage.

Comment: If I can view it, no matter in what way, I can save it. It's just a question of difficulty.

Comment: Well, it would help if, instead of downvoting, you specify what tool was used to share the video - as I said, Zoom (even paid/company versions) saves in a local file the recorded meetings. Microsoft Sharepoint, for instance, has ways to [block downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/block-downloads-for-view-only-files-in-sharepoint-and-onedrive-6051184b-62ac-4149-b874-13dcd40ef91e), and you would need to hack it to get your video file.

Comment: I've added a link which hopefully clarifies this to the question. It's not sharepoint - it's something Zoom itself offers (I think).

Comment: I've edited the answer, adding information about the specific tool used to share the recordings. I hope that helps you.